# Angular2 Unexpected value in Service. Please add annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular2 app am getting the following error **Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'ReleasesService' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.**

My **AppModule**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing } from './app.routes';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SearchFilter } from '../app/search-filter.pipe';
import { ReleasesService } from '../app/releases/releases.service';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../app/home/home.component';
import { ReleasesComponent } from '../app/releases/releases.component';
import { DistroComponent } from '../app/distro/distro.component';
import { ContactComponent } from '../app/contact/contact.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, 
                  SearchFilter,
                  HomeComponent, 
                  ReleasesComponent, 
                  ReleasesService,
                  DistroComponent, 
                  ContactComponent  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My **ReleasesService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IRelease } from './release';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ReleasesService {
  getReleases() {
    return IRelease;
  }
}
```

How to fix it? I reinstalled the *Quickstarter* (the base for my App), and having the same error when try to create the service.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`declarations` is only for declarable classes: **Components Directives and Pipes**

You can add `ReleasesService` to `providers` array

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ ReleasesService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See also

- https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-classes-should-i-add-to-declarations

Comment: it is not working for me.I endeavoured with gave providers in either its own file or in app.mudule file... can you help me in it..??

Comment: @DeepakChawla Can you reproduce it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, occurring while a project had angular2 as dependency and a project dependency (with the failing component) as well. Seems like angular2 metadata gets attached to the direct angular2 dependency, so the component in the project dependency wasn't declared in the angular2 of the project.

Workaround is to remove angular2 from the dependency (declaring it as devDependency there) and only use one angular2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the decorator has the caracter @.

If you don´t type @ before the decorator function you will have this error message

```
@Component({ selector: '...', }) -> Correct

Component({ selector: '...', }) -> ERROR MESAGE: 'add a @Pipe/@Directive/@component'
```